# Jet/Access DDL: How to create FOREIGN KEY constraints without data integrity check?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ddl, jet

When you create foreign key constraints with Access (through database schema editor), you have a choice to enable or disable the following options (actual captions may differ, I only have localized version of Access available):

```
x Enforce data integrity
  x Cascade updates
  x Cascade deletions
```

In DDL, the latter two can be represented with:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT Constraint1
  FOREIGN KEY (Field1)
  REFERENCES Table2 (Table2Field1)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But how do you simulate the case where none of the checkboxes are on, not even the "enforce integrity"?

Simply dropping "ON UPDATE/ON DELETE" clauses still produces the equivalent of "enforce integrity" constraint (and consequently requires that Field1 and Table2Field1 had indexes).

Comment: Here is a discussion that may be of interest: http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/1655289-problems-creating-relationship-ms-access-using-ddl-sql.html

Comment: What value do you see in creating relationships without referential integrity?

Comment: @HansUp: I'm writing a tool to export Access database schema and then to parse the SQL and recreate the database. If someone has this kind of relationship in their DB, I can't just ignore it.

Comment: @himself: Why not just recreate the tables in the right order for the constraints to be valid?  You will only have trouble with this, then for tables with mutual references, in which case you need to add constraints after creating one of the tables

Comment: @himself : I think you will have to use DAO as well as ADO to replicate the database. This is not the only thing that you will have problems recreating in ADO.

Comment: @himself: On second thought, why not create all the constraints after you have created all the tables?  That's what other schema-recreating tools do when they do not feel like recreating tables in the right order.

Comment: @gmagana: There's no problem with adding constraints in itself. I do it just like you suggest, first create all the tables, then alter them to add constraints. But if the original DB had "no integrity check" relationship, I have to create it somehow.

Comment: @HansUp, @Remou: Yup, I'm using DAO as well for importing comments. Just like you say, CreateRelation seems to allow this, although I'll wait a bit in case someone knows a DDL method, as it's preferable. Please suggest CreateRelation as an answer so that I can accept it later?

Comment: @himself: I see...  Does Access support the WITH NOCHECK clause in the constraint definition? See here for how it works under SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

Comment: I've built a similar tool myself. You'll find many such anomalies: things that don't show up in the INFORMATION SCHEMA but do in ADOX, things that do show up but can't be recreated via SQL DDL, a CHECK constraint definition of more than 255 characters shows as `NULL`, etc.

Comment: ...I'll happily share info if you ask questions with a `sql` tag ;)

Comment: Is your tool open source? If I have known about it before, I'd have just contributed to it instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: No, it was my vanity project, coded in Excel VBA.

Comment: ...I gave up maintaining it for Access2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing an Access 'Relationship' with a ACE/Jet `FOREIGN KEY`.

In general, you can't use SQL DDL to create Access objects (even if those objects are persisted in ACE/Jet tables). Another example is Validation Rules but you can create `CHECK` constraints using SQL DDL (in fact cannot be created any other way) which are more powerful (e.g. can be more than one per table, can reference other rows within the same table or in other tables, etc), yet Validation Rules show up in the adSchemaTableConstraints schema VIEW with CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'CHECK'.

Comment: Well, yeah. But relationships/foreign keys mostly go together, and if you check schemas (the ones you get with OpenSchema), even non-integrity-checked relationships are represented as "FOREIGN KEY" there. Also when you create a foreign key, Access automatically treats it as a relationship.

Comment: @himself: they show up in the INFORMATION SCHEMA? That doesn't sound right. If they do then I suspect a bug, I can't see the point of showing them. After all, you can create an Access Relationship on columns of differing data types!

Comment: Yup, precisely in adSchemaReferentialConstraints, adSchemaTableConstraints and adSchemaForeignKeys. I guess I'll have to find a way to tell them from normal foreing keys, too.

Comment: @himself: are you able to detect FKs created with `NO INDEX` IN SQL DDL?

Comment: From the looks of it, no: they produce the same information schema. (Maybe I can with DAO, haven't checked yet). Although, compared to dummy foreign keys, any integrity-checked foreign key produces additional UNIQUE constraint with the name of that foreign key ("Table1Table2") in adSchemaTableConstraints, so I guess this can be taken as a sign that this fkey is "real".

Comment: I just tested creating an Access Relationship (took me a while to find a machine which had it installed!) and you are indeed correct: it shows up in the FKs VIEW. My tool has a code comment: "It seems that Jet allows a FK based on a nameless PK!" I'm thinking that you should be able to detect a Relationship distinct from an FK by testing `!PK_NAME` is `Null` in the FKs recordset.

Comment: "any integrity-checked foreign key produces additional UNIQUE constraint with the name of that foreign key ("Table1Table2") in adSchemaTableConstraints" -- surely it doesn't when you create it using the `NO INDEX` keywords ?!

Comment: I was wrong, indeed. This only happens when you create the relation with Access, and it's a "one-to-one" relation. Furthermore, if you create a relation between two indexed fields with unique values, although in theory it's "one-to-one", Access displays it as one-to-many.

Comment: ..."if you create a relation" - throught DDL, not Access.

Comment: @himself: when you say "create a relation" I assume you mean "create a (foreign key) reference". 'Relation' implies a table. Yeah, I know the DAO object model has a Relations collection that is collection of Relationships and foreign keys references but I assume this is a contraction 'Relation(ship)s' and there's no need to perpetuate the misnomer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want integrity enforced then you really don't want the constraint as the purpose of a foreign key constraint is to enforce a relationship between two tables via a common field.  As best I can see it, if you don't want integrity enforced, updates cascaded, or deletes cascaded, you really don't need the constraint at all.  Just leave it off.

I suppose that in some databases (e.g. Oracle) you could create the constraint but leave it disabled - but this seems pointless except for the documentary benefit.  AFAIK constraints can't be disabled in Access, but I could be wrong.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: See my comment to the question. It might be true, but I have no control over what's in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Use the NOCHECK option while adding the foreign key constraint. For more information please see this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177463.aspx

Comment: `NOCHECK` is indeed for SQL Server.